# How should i write this Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

i m trying to write a query. The result of query is some rows from the rows containf table on the basis of their type and latest entry.

[image]

Currently the table is sorted on the basis of FK and Dates and the result should be the latest 
dates according to FK

Comment: Please improve your question. There is not enough information.

Comment: Have you tried to write the query to return these 3 rows?  Please edit the question with any attempts that you have made.

Comment: It's not really sufficient to say "I want these three rows". WHY? What about those three rows make them desirable? At first glance, the only thing they have in common is the date, so perform a query based on the date?

Comment: Yes i want to return these 3 rows

Comment: Which version of SQL Server?  This is easier in SQL 2008 and later.

Comment: Is this puzzle ? first we have to understand what you want? then will write query for You :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using [`RANK`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx),

```
WITH [Ranked] AS (
    SELECT
        RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY [FK] ASC, ORDER BY [DATES] DESC ) [Rank],
        [PK],
        [FK],
        [DATES]
    FROM [YourTable])
SELECT
    [PK],
    [FK],
    [DATES]
FROM [Ranked]
WHERE [Rank] = 1;
```

---

You'll have to tell us what happens when two rows have the same `[FK]` and `[DATES]`.

Comment: IS it work with SQL SERVER 2005 ?

Comment: @Shashank, actually yes.

Comment: Yes I m Working over SQL SERVER 2005 and i m showing a small demo table to get the answer i never face the situation as per my work i will do it on both dates and times